# Recognising visitors between domains

Tags: php, mysql

Is it at all possible to retrieve user information that can be used as a unique identifier between domains?

As a quick example of what I am trying to do (not exactly this but the theory is the same) say you had a main website at UK-news.com. You also had three other sites - England-news.com, Scotland-news.com and Wales-news.com, all hosted on the same server.

All 4 sites will share the same database and each would just pull the relevant info out of it. If a user becomes a member of one of the sites, they will also be given the option to become a member of any or all of the others. If a user signs-in to one of the sites he is a member of, and then goes to another how can I get that site to recognise him from the one he signed-in on so he is automatically logged in?

My theory was to store some user information (IP, USER_AGENT, browser, screen resolution, computer name, OS) in the database via PhP and then check against all of those as the user moves between sites. however, even checking against all of these, I am sure it will be possible for two different people to have exactly the same details.

Are there any truly unique identifiers that will guarantee that a person is recognised between domains?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: This is an example of what StackExchange doesn't do well.

Comment: the stack sites do this, you want to look in to  OAuth and its ilk

Comment: There's the way SE does it, but it isn't as automatic as you might like. Probably what scrowler is referencing is sometimes when moving between sites on SE you have to click login again, but then it sees you're already logged in (via google, for instance) and it updates.

Comment: I had considered the likes of OAuth but really wanted the sites to free of any third-party scripts.

Comment: i'm not sure what OAuth has to do with third-party scripts

Comment: @SteveBall - OAuth is a protocol, not a script. You write your own implementation of it according to [its specifications](http://oauth.net/). SE does it by allowing you to log in via a common account e.g. Google and recognising that between domains, however they force you to refresh the page if you haven't logged in for a while..

Comment: Bad turn of phrase on my part. I meant that I want everything to be written by me rather than use any ready-made solutions. It is a challenge I am setting myself to improve my development skills.

Comment: did you write php? your OS? your browser ? S.O ? ... i find it funny when people say they want to use "nothing written by others"  while using billions of lines of code written by others.

Comment: Bad turn of phrase on my part again. Using languages, OS's, servers and other software written by others, I would like to develop my skills by creating a group of linked web sites where all of the code written to create the site has been typed into Notepad++ by me!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is the configuration of your server, but. If one site is under something.domain.com, and another something2.domain.com, and the domains England-news.com and Scotland-news.com are only links to those sites, you can use url overwrite, and cookies sharing over subdomains option in php. But I think that this is not the case. So...

**There is no 100% sure user recognition.** And this is great, imagine what will happen if there would be. You can NEVER trust user data, and headers data, while sometime you can not even trust $_SERVER array. So there is no option to recognize the same user over few domains.

1) The only answer that is useful is to suggest you to share the user mysql table, and make all the logins and passwords same for each site. IN that case someone can login into another site using the same data.

2) You can try to rely on second hand services like google acount or facebook acount to verify users on your site. But you must remember that there are people without gmail and facebook, and availability of such a site will be reduced.

3) Use a serrvice like forever cookie, or something like that, but this is also not 100% sure. It is using html5 storage, flash objects, and everything to verify if this is the same user. But as far as I know, everything can be ommited, if you are patient enough.

Best regards!

Comment: Agree with you - if there was a 100% sure user recognition between domains, surely this network would be a good example of it - however, they implement a "best we can do" type of solution

Comment: It does look like this may be far too complicated for what it is worth, especially if no solution will be 100% accurate. I have found a solution suggesting using iFrames to secretly have a page of all sites included all others but it doesn't feel right?

Comment: Never thought about iframes as an answer. There is a possibility that it will work, but taking into acount safety, and the complexity of the problem... I'm not 100% convinced if it is worth. But  I will make a research about iframes safety, as it sounds complicated, but promising :).